# Nginx Rewrite Rule

Tags: nginx

I need to write a generic nginx rule such that

subdomainmysite.in is redirected to www.subdomainmysite.in

randommysite.in is redirected to www.randommysite.in]

xyzmysite.in is redirected to www.xyzmysite.in

and so on

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
server {
    server_name ~^(?!www\.);
    return 301 http://www.$host/;
}
```

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html
- http://nginx.org/r/server_name
- http://nginx.org/r/return
- man pcrepattern
- man pcresyntax